# Why is my route returning 500 error?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to write my first Vue component and make it post some data to my Laravel backend. For some reson the post returns a 500 error. Why is this? And yes, the csrf token is part of the headers that gets sent.

VUE COMPONENT:

```
<template>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="letsTalk">
        <div class="input-group">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="message" placeholder="Type here my friend..." ref="messageInput" autofocus>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                message: 'joel',
                messageInput: []
            }
        },
        created(){

        },
        methods: {
            letsTalk: function () {
                this.$refs.messageInput.focus()
                this.message = ''
                this.success = function(m) {
                    console.log('success', m)
                }
                this.error = function(m) {
                    console.log('error', m)
                }

                this.$http.post( '/api/messages', [this.message])
                    .then(this.success, this.error);

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

ROUTES:

```
    Route::post('/api/messages', 'Messages@send');
```

CONTROLLER

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Log;

    class Messages extends Controller
    {
        public function send() {
            return json_encode('this works')
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you get an internal server error, it generally helps to examine the error logs and **find out what the error message says**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check under the networks tab in your browser's `developer console` so you can see what is happening, or check your logs.

If that's your copy and pasted code then you have missed a semi-colon at the end of your `json_encoded` line, which should be:

`return json_encode('this works');`

It's always a good idea to try to include the semi-colons in `javascript` as well if you're flipping between writing `javascript` and `php`, because `php` requires the `semi-colon`, so it's easy to miss them out if you don't add them habitually.

Comment: Thanks! the semi-colon fixed it!